# Is the YouTube Google Data API (GDATA) deprecated?

Tags: api, youtube, gdata

I'm about to start a project that requires some simple `YouTube` non-write data operations, like gathering users playlists and videos. I read that the `YouTube 2.0 API` is deprecated, but I don't really want to use `OAuth` authentication required for API 3.0.

Does this mean that the `GDATA API` deprecated (in particular this: https://gdata.youtube.com/demo/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google's GData API for YouTube was deprecated on 2014-03-14 according to their api status [page](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/). This was after your original question was asked, but I'm leaving this here for other's (like myself) who are trying to keep track of which api is current..

Answer (score 0):

While you do not want to use [OAuth 2.0 authentication](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication), it would appear that you will need to make the transition to use `YouTube` API 3.0 version.  If you do want your project to have a long life, you should make the effort to move to the new authentication mechanism. This will serve you well if you access other Google (and many other cloud service) apis.